# User likes structure in firestore to avoid high read count

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a 'likes' collection that stores a user_id and object_id that is the doc id of what is being liked. If a user has say 5,000 likes/follows and I want them to be able to review their previous likes, I would have to query based on the user_id which would result in 5,000 reads unless I limit how many are returned. I know that I could keep an array of every id that is liked, but since the amount of user likes has no limit, it is possible that the document size limit would be reached.

What is the best option for keeping track of user likes without having to read every matching doc in the likes collection? Should I have a subcollection on 'users' so /users/user_id/likes and add a new doc each time the limit is reached?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "add a new doc each time the limit is reached"?

Comment: Means when the document storing the list of IDs that liked reaches Firestores maximum document size, make a new document containing the overflow IDs